# Git pull from/push to a specific branch with magit commands in elisp

Tags: init-file, magit, git

When I run magit commands through the magit interface it runs those commands relative to the branch/repository I am currently visiting. However, I am trying to write some code in my config file that will automatically push to or pull from a specific repo, and am not sure how to format magit commands in elisp.

For example, the documentation for `magit-pull-from-upstream` says:

> Pull from the upstream of the current branch.

But what determines the current branch, and how can I specify it? `magit-push-current-to-upstream` similarly mentions the "current branch".

What I am looking for is a way to call these commands **from my config file in elisp code** (or similar commands, if these are not the appropriate ones) while specifying which branch of which repo to pull from/push to. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `(call-process "git" ...)` or similar instead of trying to do it using Magit's API?

Comment: @Constantine Ah, I can try that. I have been using magit so much recently, I tend to think about doing everything related to git through its API, but perhaps it is not suited for this particular use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many Magit *commands*, the push commands are not really intended to be used non-interactively.

Currently no warning is shown if you use them non-interactively, but that might change. The commands are not considered part of any application *programming* interface, and I don't make any promises about their "interfaces" staying the same.

Anyway, assuming you know elisp and are also somewhat familiar with Emacs programming concepts (in particular how commands work), then I would assume it to be fairly obvious what you have to do, after looking at the various push commands:

```
(let ((default-directory "/path/to/local/repo/"))
  (magit-git-push (magit-get-current-branch)
                  (magit-get-upstream-branch)
                  (magit-push-arguments)))
```

Of course you should also handle the cases when there is no current branch or when it has no upstream. Again, look at `magit-push-current-to-upstream` for one way of doing that. And since you don't actually want to push to the upstream (I believe), you'll have to adjust that part too.

> But what determines the current branch, and how can I specify it?

Look at the code, specifically inside the `interactive` form; there `magit-get-current-branch` is being called. That then becomes the value of the `BRANCH` argument, but only when the command is being called interactively. When it is being called non-interactively as in `(magit-push-current-to-upstream ...)`, then the `interactive` form is irrelevant, and you have to provide the arguments yourself, which makes it kind of pointless to use this command/function in the first place.

Better use the low-level function as shown above, or if you want to avoid having to write more code than absolutely necessary, then call the command (pseudo-)interactively:

```
(call-interactively #'magit-push-current-to-upstream)
```

Answer (score 0):

Current branch is the one currently checked out.

To use a non-current branch and non-default upstream, use the <kbd>e</kbd>lsewhere option of `push` or <kbd>o</kbd>ther of `pull`, which in turn run `magit-push-elsewhere` and `magit-pull`, respectivelly.

```
(cd "/path/to/the/repo")
(magit-pull "origin" "master")
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know how to do it from my config file in elisp code, not interactively. I will be in a state where I am not visiting a git repo and so magit will not know (without being told) which branch to push to or pull from. I want to know how to tell it

Comment: @elethan: updated.

Comment: Again, I don't want to do it interactively. I will try to clarify in the question.

Comment: @elethan: Sure, so use the functions I gave you.

Comment: My question is asking how to use those commands in elisp on their own or as part of a custom function. For example, calling `(magit-pull)` from my config file will not work, because I have not specified which repo to pull what remote from. The documentation shows the form `(magit-pull SOURCE ARGS)` but it is not clear to me what format `SOURCE` should be in and what `ARGS` to provide - hence my question.

Comment: @elethan: They're just strings. See the update again.

Comment: You could wrap it in `(with-temp-buffer ...)`.

Comment: It would be better to use `(let ((default-directory "/path/to/repo")) (magit-pull...))` instead of `cd`, I think.